# Bilinear form and isomorphism

Tags: analysis, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Consider
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m) = \{ B: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m ; ~B \ \text{ is bilinear}\}$$

show that

\begin{split}
   \Phi: & \ \mathcal{L}\big( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \big) \longrightarrow \qquad \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m) \\
   & \qquad  \qquad  T \qquad \ \ \quad \longmapsto  \ \Phi(T)[x,y] := T(x)(y)
\end{split}

is a canonical isomorphism.

My first question is: I must show that this is linear, right? So we do

\begin{split}
\Phi(\lambda T+S)[x,y] & = (\lambda T+S)(x)(y) \\
& =(\lambda T(x)+S(x))(y) \\ 
& = \lambda T(x)(y) +  S(x)(y) \\ 
& = \lambda \Phi(T)[x,y] +\Phi(S)[x,y].
\end{split}

I think that it's right, but i would appreciate any comment on this. Moving on, we know that $$Dim \ \mathcal{L}\big( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \big) = Dim \ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m)$$

so it is enought to prove that $\Phi$ is injective, I'm working on that part, but i would like to know if it is the "right" idea.

Also, I'm having some hard time on understand how the elements of $\mathcal{L}\big( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \big).$ Any recomendation on references in this topic will help me!

Comment: Show the bijectivity directly by equivalence. You can also work with $L(E,L(F,G))$ where $E,F,G$ are normed spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof that $\Phi$ is linear is ok, but before moving on, although trivial, you should at least mention that $\Phi$ does take values in $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$. The quantity $\Phi(T)(x,y)=T(x)(y)$ is bilinear in $x$ and $y$ because $T$ is linear and because $T(x)$ is linear.

That said, given $B\in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$, let $\Psi(B):\Bbb R^n \to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^n)$ be given by $\Psi(B)(x)(y)=B(x,y)$. Show that $\Psi$ is the desired inverse.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some example of an element in $\mathcal{L}\big( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \big).$?

Comment: Take any bilinear map $B$, and so $x\mapsto B(x,\cdot)$ is an example. Because of the isomorphism, those are all of them. You can think of a parametric family of linear maps, also linear on the parameter itself.